# How Spark Reads And Process Data In AWS EMR If The Total Cluster Resource Memory In EMR Is Less Than The Data Set Read From AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Let's say I am having a AWS cluster with 1 master node instance, 5 core nodes instance and Task nodes which can be Auto-Scaled up to 16 instances as max. Each Master/Task/core nodes having below configuration :

```
Master Node : 16Vcore , 128 GB Memory, 600 SSD GB storage
Each Core Node : 4Vcore,16 GB memory,64 GB EBS storage
Each Task Node : 4Vcore,16 GB memory,50 GB EBS storage
```

Now with above configuration cumulative memory available for all task nodes are **16*16=256 GB** 
and cumulative EBS storage available is **50GB*16=800GB** . So here are my two doubts (Since I am trying to completely understand how it works)

1. If I am having a HIVE external table with storage location as s3 of size 500 GB (which is greater than the total memory (RAM) available for all the task nodes) and I need to read all the data for performing some analytical transformations using spark, how spark will handle that
2. Lets say in above scenario,  spark spills the overflowing data into disk (which I am not sure,but still assuming).But what will happen if the data set in S3 is of more than 1 TB , which is more than the total storage(800 GB) + memory (256 GB) =  1056 GB

Answer (score 3):

Spark was build to be able to process more data than can fit into memory.
Here are some points that could help you understand:

1. It's very unlikely that all the data needs to be in memory at once to perform queries
2. Spark will split data into [partitions](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html). So you only require minimum as much memory as will be stored in one partition. The number of partitions you can change yourself. For example 1TB / 1000 partitions = 1 GB per partition. And you have that much memory.
3. How much data will be in partition also depends on nature of your data and query.
4. The real limits could cause `join` and `partition` operations in spark, since they require to put data with the same keys on the same partitions. And if you have small number of keys, or some key appears many times - you can have too much data on the same partition.

Comment: I understood the concept of partitioning, But what confuses me when if I need to perform aggregate functions or joins over this entire 1 TB data , shuffling phases are involved. And I need to make this entire 1 TB data in to seperate groups either with the help of total memory. Even if it's 1000 1 GB partitions, all need to be stored and processed in available memory only right and here I am having only 256 GB memory available as a whole . So how it will handle ?

Comment: Join is done by `key` - one or multiple columns with specific values. This `key` will be used to create partitions. At the same time only 1 partition is required to be in memory to do join, because all data that is participating in join (with the same key) will be in same partition.

Comment: So , Say I am reading 2 external tables from S3 using spark each of 600GB for joining. Now let's assume  I am joining on a particular ID , let's say PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID , say I am having as a total of 4 such IDs. So each partition will be having data for same ID from both the tables. Again let's assume I am having 200GB data for an ID from both the tables, Now my question is while this join happens on this 200GB data for a particular ID, where the rest of the data which is waiting to be processed will reside? In work node EBS storage or S3?

Comment: You're almost correct. Different ID's still might get into same partition, but in general - you will have 4 partitions with data. Take a look on this topic - https://medium.com/parrot-prediction/partitioning-in-apache-spark-8134ad840b0 - it might help you to get idea of partitioning in spark. Remaining data will be either spilled on disk (if you will use `persist()`) or will be re-calculated - for example all the data will be read again. Look here - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd.html for `resilience`